# How to access outer table data in join where

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I access data from an outer table in a SELECT, and use it in an WHERE inside a JOIN estructure?

Below is the current query:

```
    SELECT
        cvl.id caracteristica_valor_id,
        cvl.nome caracteristica_valor_nome,
        cvl.valor caracteristica_valor_valor,
        ctp.id caracteristica_tipo_id,
        ctp.nome caracteristica_tipo_nome,
        ctp.codigo caracteristica_tipo_codigo,
        ctp.tipo caracteristica_tipo_tipo,
        COUNT(DISTINCT var.id_perfil_produto) quantidade_itens
    FROM
        caracteristica_variacao cvr
    INNER JOIN caracteristica_valor cvl ON  cvl.id = cvr.id_caracteristica_valor
    INNER JOIN caracteristica_tipo ctp ON ctp.id = cvl.id_caracteristica_tipo
    INNER JOIN variacao var ON var.id = cvr.id_variacao
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ppr.id perfil_produto_id
        FROM
            perfil_produto ppr
        INNER JOIN produto pro ON pro.id = ppr.id_produto
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT ppr2.id AS id_perfil_sub,a
                COUNT(var.id) AS qtd_variacoes,
                SUM(var.quantidade_estoque) AS quantidade_estoque,
                COALESCE(SUM(var.quantidade_estoque_reservada),0) AS quantidade_estoque_reservada,
                MIN(var.disponibilidade) AS disponibilidade,
                MIN(var.frete_gratis) AS frete_gratis,
                MIN(var.preco_venda) AS preco_venda,
                MAX(var.preco_listagem) AS preco_listagem
            FROM
                variacao var
            LEFT JOIN perfil_produto ppr2 ON ppr2.id = var.id_perfil_produto
            LEFT JOIN caracteristica_variacao cvr_1 ON cvr_1.id_variacao = var.id
            LEFT JOIN caracteristica_valor cvl_1 ON cvl_1.id = cvr_1.id_caracteristica_valor
            LEFT JOIN caracteristica_tipo ctp_1 ON ctp_1.id = cvl_1.id_caracteristica_tipo
            WHERE
                var.disponibilidade = 1
                AND(
                    ctp_1.codigo = 'tamanho' AND cvl_1.valor IN('p')
                )
            GROUP BY
                ppr2.id
        ) AS grp_var ON grp_var.id_perfil_sub = ppr.id
        INNER JOIN produto_categoria prc ON pro.id = prc.produto_id
        INNER JOIN categoria cat ON prc.categoria_id = cat.id
        WHERE
            pro.disponibilidade = 1 AND prc.categoria_id IN (164, 165, 166)
     ) AS produto ON produto.perfil_produto_id = var.id_perfil_produto
    GROUP BY
        cvl.id
    ORDER BY
        ctp.tipo ASC,
        ctp.id
```

I need the field `ctp.codigo` from the outer table inside thist part:

```
WHERE
    var.disponibilidade = 1
    AND(
        ctp_1.codigo = 'tamanho' AND cvl_1.valor IN('p')
    )
```

for this section to be as follows:

```
WHERE
    var.disponibilidade = 1
    AND(
        (ctp.codigo != 'tamanho' AND ctp_1.codigo = 'tamanho' AND cvl_1.valor IN('p'))
        OR
        (ctp.codigo = 'tamanho')
    )
```

Comment: The rule of thumb, which fits in m ost cases is: *conditions on the Outer table in WHERE, conditions on the Inner table are ANDed to the ON*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to reference columns from the outer query from inside an inline view query.

In the MySQL venacular, the inline view query is called a "derived table". And that name makes sense, because of the way MySQL processes it. The execution plan first materializes the inline view query into a temporary(-ish) table. Once that is done, then the outer query can run, referencing the contents of the derived table.

MySQL doesn't have available the columns from the outer query at the time the inline view query runs.

---

It is possible to reference columns from the outer query inside a subquery that appears for example in the SELECT list, or in the WHERE clause. We call a subquery that references columns from outer query a "correlated subquery".